# I'm using a Room database in Android Studio, and I can't seem to update correctly a field of an item in the database

Tags: android, database, android-studio, android-room

I've been doing Android Studio for a month only and I've got to say I'm kind of confused with Room database, I'm sorry if the question sounds confused.

I'm using a Room database as stated, here are my Database-related classes:

```
@Entity(tableName="board")
public class BoardItem {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name="board_id")
    private int boardId;
    @ColumnInfo(name="board_name")
    private String boardName;
    @ColumnInfo(name="board_description")
    private String boardDescription;
    @ColumnInfo(name="board_image_list")
    @TypeConverters(ImageListTypeConverter.class)
    private List<ImageItem> boardImageList;

    public BoardItem(String boardName, String boardDescription){
        this.boardName = boardName;
        this.boardDescription = boardDescription;
        this.boardImageList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public int getBoardId() { return boardId; }

    public String getBoardName() {
        return boardName;
    }

    public String getBoardDescription() {
        return boardDescription;
    }

    public String getPhotosCount() {
        return String.valueOf(this.boardImageList.size());
    }
    public void setBoardId(int boardId) {
        this.boardId = boardId;
    }

    public List<ImageItem> getBoardImageList() {
        return boardImageList;
    }

    public void setBoardImageList(List<ImageItem> list) { this.boardImageList = list; }
```

```
@Dao
public interface BoardItemDAO {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    void addBoardItem(BoardItem boardItem);

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * from board ORDER BY board_id DESC")
    LiveData<List<BoardItem>> getBoardItems();

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * from board ORDER BY board_id DESC")
    List<BoardItem> getBoardItemsNow();

}
```

```
@Database(entities =  {BoardItem.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class BoardItemDatabase  extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract BoardItemDAO boardItemDAO();

    //Singleton
    private static volatile BoardItemDatabase INSTANCE;
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 4;
    static final ExecutorService databaseWriteExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);

    static BoardItemDatabase getDatabase(final Context context){

        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (BoardItemDatabase.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), BoardItemDatabase.class, "board_database")
                            .allowMainThreadQueries()
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }

        return INSTANCE;
    }

}
```

```
//Repository

public class BoardItemRepository {

    private BoardItemDAO boardItemDAO;
    private LiveData<List<BoardItem>> boardItemList;
    private List<BoardItem> boardItemListNow;

    public BoardItemRepository (Application application) {
        BoardItemDatabase db = BoardItemDatabase.getDatabase(application);
        boardItemDAO = db.boardItemDAO();
        boardItemList = boardItemDAO.getBoardItems();
        boardItemListNow = boardItemDAO.getBoardItemsNow();
    }

    //Room executes all queries on a separate thread
    //Observed LiveData will notify the observer when data has changed
    public LiveData<List<BoardItem>> getBoardItemList() { return boardItemList; }

    //this method is called on a non-UI thread or the app will throw an exception. Room ensures
    //that there are no long running operations on the main thread, blocking the UI.
    public void addBoardItem(final BoardItem boardItem) {
        BoardItemDatabase.databaseWriteExecutor.execute(() -> boardItemDAO.addBoardItem(boardItem));
    }

    public List<BoardItem> getBoardItemListNow() {return boardItemListNow; }

}
```

Note that BoardItem and ImageItem are classes I made myself: a board is supposed to contain multiple ImageItems.

My boardItem has different fields, one of which is a **list of ImageItems**.
Now, in a specific fragment I try to **update this list of ImageItems** in a board that already exists in my database, which is the board with id = 0 (the very first board in the db). I try to retrieve the list from the Database and replace it with a new one.

I have used LiveData in certain cases to update the view of my app when the item change, but I have non LiveData methods for this specific piece of my code I need to change my database as soon as I click the button that contains this code:

```
List<BoardItem> boardItems = boardListViewModel.getBoardItemsNow();

newList = boardItems.get(0).getBoardImageList();
newList.add(newItem);
boardItems.get(0).setBoardImageList(newList);
```

When I click the button, the code is executed with no errors, but the database isn't updated; it contains the list as it was before, without the new item.

Thanks in advance, again I'm sorry if this sounds confusing!

**EDIT:**
here's my ViewModel:

```
public class BoardListViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private final MutableLiveData<BoardItem> boardSelected = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private LiveData<List<BoardItem>> boardItems;
    private List<BoardItem> boardItemsNow;

    public BoardListViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        BoardItemRepository repo = new BoardItemRepository(application);
        boardItems = repo.getBoardItemList();
        boardItemsNow = repo.getBoardItemListNow();
    }

    public void select(BoardItem boardItem) {
        boardSelected.setValue(boardItem);
    }

    public LiveData<BoardItem> getSelected() {
        return boardSelected;
    }

    public LiveData<List<BoardItem>> getBoardItems() {
        return boardItems;
    }

    public BoardItem getBoardItem(int position) {
        return boardItems.getValue() == null ? null : boardItems.getValue().get(position);
    }

    public List<BoardItem> getBoardItemsNow() { return boardItemsNow; }
}
```

Comment: how are you using the livedata?

Comment: @iamanbansal I'm using livedata in another fragment. I have a recycler view and everytime the data changes I update the recycler view:
`boardListViewModel = new ViewModelProvider((ViewModelStoreOwner)activity)
.get(BoardListViewModel.class);

boardListViewModel.getBoardItems().observe((LifecycleOwner) activity, boardItems -> adapter.setData(boardItems));`

Comment: what does `setData`  function do?

Comment: Use insert method to persist the data?

Comment: Can you show your `view model` ?

Comment: @DươngMinh I added my viewmodel to the question.

Comment: @iamanbansal `setData` function saves the list obtained from the ViewModel in the adapter and uses it to display the elements in the recycler view through the adapter itself.

Comment: Are you calling `notifyDataSetChanged` function after updating the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your issue is that you are not updating but attempting to add (insert) a new item (row) via :-

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
void addBoardItem(BoardItem boardItem);
```

As the boardid already exists and that it is the primary key, which is implicitly unique, a conflict occurs, and this conflict is ignored, thus the new row is not added and the database remains unchanged.

What you should be doing is updating the existing row, so you want an [@Update](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Update#onConflict()) dao.

So add and then use the following dao :-

```
@Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
int updateBoardItem(BoardItem boardItem);
```

- the `int` returned is the number of rows that have been update (you would expect 1, 0 if a conflict resulted in the update being ignored).

Comment: I guess I would implement an updateBoardItem method in my repo, writing something like `BoardItemDatabase.databaseWriteExecutor.execute(() -> boardItemDAO.updateBoardItem(boardItem));` . However I'm not sure how I'm supposed to check if the item correctly updated and therefore returning the correct int.

Comment: I've applied your suggestion and now it works perfectly! I didn't think it would be as easy as making an update specific query.